# reference to a std::vector of derived class pointers as input parameter to a function

Tags: c++

First of all I'd like to apologize if there's another question like this one and I didn't find it. I've been trying but since the problem is quite specific I couldn't find one.

Now, the problem. I have a Base class and a Derived class (say BNode and DNode ), and I have a std::vector of BNode*. I have also a function which receives a reference to a vector of these pointers. I'm having trouble when trying to pass a std::vector of pointers to derived objects as a parameter to this function:

```
class BNode
{
};

class DNode : public BNode
{
};

class Other
{
function(std::vector<BNode*>& inputVector) { } 
}
```

When trying to pass a vector of pointers to the derived class, the error I'm receiving from VS is:

```
1> error C2664: 'Other::function' : cannot convert parameter 1 'std::vector<T>' to 'std::vector<T> &'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=DNode *
1>        ]
1>        and
1>        [
1>            T=BNode *
1>        ]
```

Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the ' : public BNode' ...

Comment: http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/136191-passing-derived-class-object-array-place-base-class-object-array - See Andrew Koenig  and Alf P. Steinbach say why it isn't allowed in C++

Comment: what's your question now? Would you like to understand the reason of this or are you looking for a solution?

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114819/how-get-a-vectorderived-into-a-function-that-expects-a-vectorbase-as-argume

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that even if `DNode` derives from `BNode`, `std::vector<DNode*>` doesn't derive from `std::vector<BNode*>`.

Therefore, the compiler does not know how to convert from one type to the other.

You might however do:

```
std::vector<BNode*> bnode_list;
std::vector<DNode*> dnode_list(bnode_list.begin(), bnode_list.end());
```

Comment: this is a very nice solution: the only suggestion that works nicely for constructor arguments as well

Answer (score 3):

This is because vector< Bnode* > and vector< Dnode* > do not have any parent-child relation. They are different objects.

I guess you have created a vector like std::vector< DNode* > dnodevec; 
Instead you can create std::vector< BNode* > dnodevec; Being the vector of base class pointers you can safely insert any DNode type pointer in the vector.

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't support [covariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/csharpfaq/covariance-and-contravariance-faq) in templates. An `std::vector<DNode*>` cannot be assigned to an `std::vector<BNode*>` even if `DNode` derives from `BNode`.

For your code to work, you should only declare vectors of pointers to BNode and populate them with pointers to DNode as needed.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are probably calling `Other::function` something like this:

```
std::vector<DNode *> v;
// put stuff into v
Other o;
o.function(v);
```

Which won't compile, as `std::vector<DNode *>` is a distinct type to `std::vector<BNode *>`.

What may be suitable is:

```
std::vector<BNode *> v;
// You can put DNode * items into v
Other o;
o.function(v);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, what you want is not possible in C++, because `vector<BNode*>` and `vector<DNode*>` are considered to be unrelated types (even though there is a clear relation between `BNode` and `DNode`).

Consider the following code:

```
class BNode
{
};

class DNode : public BNode
{
};

class XNode : public BNode
{
};

void function(std::vector<BNode*>& inputVector) 
{
  inputVector.push_back(new XNode); // This will work, as XNode derived from BNode
} 

int main()
{
  std::vector<DNode*> vec;

  function(vec); // Suppose this would work
  // Then now, vec would contain a pointer to the unrelated class XNode!!
}
```

Comment: That is true in this case, would not apply if the vector were immutable. C++ is somewhat flawed in this regard, although if the purpose is to call some virtual method on every item, it is possible to do with for_each.

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector` is not [covariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)).

In general, you should not pass a vector of `DNode *` as a vector of `BNode *`. If `function` adds or replaces pointers to a subclass of `BNode` different from `DNode`, you would get non-`DNode` pointers in your `DNode *` vector.

You better change your types as explained in the other answers.

But contrary to what other answers say, it **is** possible to pass a vector of `DNode *` if `function` only reads the vector. To mark it so, change its signature to accept a `const` reference. Then you can pass your `DNode *` vector as follows:

```
function(reinterpret_cast<const std::vector<BNode *> &>(vec));
```

`reinterpret_cast` is generally dangerous and you should avoid it unless you know **very well** what you are doing. Here, you are circumventing the C++ type system to treat a vector of `DNode *` as a vector of `BNode *`. Raw pointers are primitive types with the same binary representation regardless of the pointed-to type. Therefore the vectors of both pointer types are runtime compatible.