# C++: Can I cast a vector <derived_class> to a vector <base_class> during a function call?

Tags: c++, stl, vector, casting

I have a existed class and function which look like this:

```
Class base_class{
    ...
}

void Func(...,vector<base_class> &vec_b,...){
    // inside the function, the vector vec_b is being re-organized and re-sized
}
```

and I defined a derived class which looks like:

```
Class derived_class: public base_class{
    ...
}
```

Now, without changing the function `Func`, can I pass a `vector<derived_class>` into `Func`, ex:

```
void main(){
    vector <derived_class> d;
    Func(...,d,...);
}
```

such that the derived class `d` undergoes the same re-organizing and re-sizing?
I know I can cast derived class to base class in a function call with no problem, but once with a vector into play, there seems to be difficulties? I can't find the answer online, so any suggestions or help is greatly appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Your vectors are holding objects by value, not by pointer, so you can't have polymorphic behavior anyway. I.e., what's the point?

Comment: Related to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/114883/8747.

Comment: A somewhat related thing: [http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#conversion](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#conversion)

Comment: I found [jimc's answer in this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/34099/#msg183879) to be very comprehensible for this complex question.

Answer (score 4):

This only works if you're using pointers.

If you're not using pointers, then there is a chance for slicing to occur. Eg.

```
class Base {
  protected:
    int foo;
};

class Child : public Base {
    int bar;
};
```

The `class Base` contains only a single int called `foo`, and the `class Child` contains two ints, `foo` and `bar`.

```
Child f;
Base sliced = (Child)f;
```

This will slice the child, causing it to remove some of the data from the object. You will not be able to cast the parent back into the child class, not unless your using pointers.

So, if you changed your `vector<>` to have pointers instead of instances of the class then you can cast back and forth between parent/child.

Using something like:

```
vector<Base*> vec;
vec[0] = static_cast<Base*>(new Child());

...
Func(vec);
...
```

Would allow you to cast the members of your vector into their child classes.

Answer (score 3):

No. Even if an A is a B, a `vector<A>` is not a `vector<B>`.

To pass one in place of the other, you can pass a vector of pointers (or use a Boost ptr_vector). Alternatively, you may be able to use a template to allow passing a vector of anything that provides the right interface.

Either of these will require changing your function though -- there's essentially no way to avoid that (and still provide the functionality you want).

Comment: Are you sure *you can pass a vector of pointers* is okay here?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: A `vector<derived *>` isn't convertible to a `vector<base *>`--but the pointers in a `vector<base *>` can point to either base or derived objects. If, however, you start with a `vector<derived *>`, it's up to you to copy those pointers into a `vector<base *>` before passing it to the function.

Comment: Oh, I see what you meant now.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot convert between vectors of different types. However, you can achieve what you're trying to do by making `Func` a template. It probably won't require you to change any code in the actual function body, but it depends on what you're doing.

```
template<typename T>
void Func(..., vector<T> &vec_b, ...){
    // inside the function, the vector vec_b is being re-organized and re-sized
}
```

Comment: The OP said "without changing Func."

Answer (score 2):

No.

You can let `Func` take `vector <base_class*>` and let the point elements in the `vector <base_class*>` point to `derived_class` instances.

Answer (score 0):

Substituting a vector of a base class with a vector of a derived class won't work if the two classes have different sizes.  This is because the vector stores contiguous instances of the type internally, so the vector of bases would think the second element was in a different location than it actually is.  You could use vectors of pointers, however.

Comment: Wouldn't this require changing func?