# Can c++ cast vector<Derived*> to vector<Base*>?

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

I want to create a generic function which gets vector types as argument.
Derived1, Derived2, ... are derived (simply) from Base

I tried something like this:
int function (vector& foo)
It didn't work.
Could you tell me, what is the best generic solution for this problem?

Comment: No. Looking for the duplicate.

Comment: Also this: [Getting a vector<Derived*> into a function that expects a vector<Base*>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114819/getting-a-vectorderived-into-a-function-that-expects-a-vectorbase/114883#114883)

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz The first duplicate actually says "yes" :) Probably hitting some UB, but it can work

Comment: @deviantfan what? Where? Oh that's the dupe suggested by Singer I think.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz `To pass one in place of the other, you can pass a vector of pointers ` etc.etc. in the first answer

Comment: @deviantfan Wut. Weird. I'd ask Jerry if that's what he indeed meant.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the duplication.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz While I agree that it is not ok and UB, in the end both contain only addressess, so with some matching casts (on elements and vectors (with detour through a vector pointer)) it probably will work.

Comment: @deviantfan I don't know about you, but I don't write code that has such assumptions in it.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Me neither :) As said, I don't think it's ok, neither in practice nor in a +4 answer there

Comment: since boost came out, and later c++11, who the hell stores naked pointers in vectors anyway? People who do that should be shipped off to re-education centres.